# AngularJS controller inside directive with binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this simple code of my directive:

```
app.directive('ngModal', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: document.getElementById('ng-modal').innerHTML,
    replace: true,
    controller : "@",
    name:"controllerName",
  }
})

<ng-modal controller-name="ModalCtrl"></ng-modal>
```

And this is my controller:

```
app.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.model = 'default text'
}])

<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="model">
</div>
```

I want, that model field inside my Directive will updated automatically. But I see "default text" always inside directive and changed inside controller. How can I bind it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a service to keep information between controllers. Controllers are always created per "view" so your ng-modal and div have different controllers in use, this is why model data is not updated between them.

Fast example:

```
app.service('sharedData', function() {
  var sharedData = {
    field: 'default text'
  };

  return sharedData;
});

app.directive('ngModal', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '',
    replace: true,
    controller : "@",
    name:"controllerName",
  }
});

app.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedData', function ($scope, sharedData) {
  $scope.model = sharedData;
}]);

<ng-modal controller-name="ModalCtrl">{{model.field}}</ng-modal>

<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="model.field">
</div>
```